# Problem with VisualBasic

Tags: vb.net

I have a silly error that I am unable to resolve.  I try to debug, and when I debug I get the following error

> ERROR "Visual Studio cannot start
>   debugging because debut target
>   'C:\Documents and
>   Settings\user\Desktop\programs6\HuricaneSeasonStatistics\bin\Debug\HuricaneStatistics.exe"
>   is missing.  Please build the project
>   and retry, or set the OutputPath and
>   AssemblyName properties appropriate to
>   point a the correct location for the
>   target assembly."

I am fairly sure the error is in the OutputPath and or AssemblyName. but I am not sure where to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that it is actually building.  i.e. there is an exe where it thinks there is one.

Comment: I do see the following file in the ...\bin\HuricaneStatistics.exe and ...\bin\HuricaneStatistics.exe.manifest

Comment: HuricaneSeasonStatistics.exe sorry about that.

Comment: Not sure if it a typo, here or in the original post, but its looking in bin/debug for the exe.

Comment: Yes, when I view in the frmHuricane.vb[Design]* \bin\HuricaneSeasonStatistics.exe and ...\bin\HuricaneSeasonStatistics.exe.manifest exist.

Comment: Brian - It was a weird error and some how I fixed it.  I do not think it was being built correctly.  Go figure.  Thank you.